# Unable to import installed modules into my code

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I can't import modules of any kind. I know that I have the modules installed, and that they are inputted correctly, but it still does not work, and gives me this full error when trying to `import numpy as np`:

```
C:\Users\alecd\Desktop\Code\PYTHON\chess>C:/Users/alecd/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Users/alecd/Desktop/Code/PYTHON/chess/chess_board.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/alecd/Desktop/Code/PYTHON/chess/chess_board.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I keep all my code in a lot of folders, and when I take the code out of the folders it works. However I don't want all of my code to be in one massive folder. I tried creating a new `PYTHONPATH`, which I believe will work but I would have to append all of my scripts every time, which would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: check to be in the right environment

Comment: do a ``pip freeze`` and see if your on right env.

Comment: Please use a virtualenv and don't edit PYTHONPATH

Comment: If you have python2 and python3 both installed, and you used 'pip install package' to install packages, try using pip3. Ex: 'pip3 install numpy'

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem a week ago and found out that I installed 2 python envs at once. One was from original website(python.org) the other was from Microsoft Store. I kept installing modules on one and using another to run my code.

If you are using some kind of text editor(I was using Visual Studio Code) you need to select the right environment for compiler.

On Visual Studio Code you change compiler from left-bottom corner
[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wapZ0.png)